# React: remove object inside an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following structure assembled inside a state (data, setData):

```
[
  {
    4b080412-b22c-40fe-a67e-510f96d50063:{
      id: 1231,
      name: "Anna",
      department: "Business"
    }
  },
  {
    8d319764-a49e-4465-a166-a701a5cc2b77:{
      id: 456,
      name: "Tony",
      department: "Marketing"
    }
  },
  {
    23ea617b-210e-4329-9ab1-ecd2afa12e4d:{
      id: 99,
      name: "Francis",
      department: "Sales"
    }
  },
]
```

I put an 'onClick' on the button passing an 'ID' (eg: '23ea617b-210e-4329-9ab1-ecd2afa12e4d').

But I am not able to delete the related ID. I tried the following ways, but without success:

```
  const handleClick = (identifier: string) => {        
    setData(
      data.filter((el: any) => {
        if (el[identifier] !== undefined) return el[identifier].product !== id;
      }),
    );
```

also:

```
  const handleClick = (identifier: string) => {        
    delete data[identifier]
  );
```

Can anyone help me with how can I access this ID?

Comment: `el[identifier].product` where is the `product` property?

Comment: This structure is pretty hard to use. The key in each object should probably be a key-value pair to remove a layer of nesting. Otherwise you have to do `Object.keys(obj)[0]` just to figure out what the identifier is.

Comment: Thank you, my friends! solved with: Object.keys(obj)[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running this one:

```js
const handleClick = (identifier: string) => {
  setData(
    data.filter((obj) => {
      return Object.keys(obj)[0] !== identifier;
    }),
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code, it works for me.

```
setData(data.filter(el => el[identifier] === undefined))
```

Comment: index.tsx:124 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0d9ce0a2-71cf-4128-9bd2-c98c20c379ee')

Answer (score 1):

hi Nosredna I have gone through the approach u have used, and have some logical issues

you can try it like this

```
const handleClick = (identifier: string) => {        
     const newArr=data.filter(el=>!el[identifier])
     setData(newArr);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If `d` is non-null and `identifier` is present in `d`, then return false to filter the item out -

```js
const onRemove = identifier =>
  setData(data.filter(d => !(d && d[identifier])))
```

<kbd>Run</kbd> the demo below and verify the result in your own browser -

```js
function App({ initData = [] }) {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(initData)
  const onRemove = uuid => event =>
    setData(data.filter(d => !(d && d[uuid])))
  return <div>
    {data.map((d, key) =>
      <Item key={key} item={d} uuid={Object.keys(d)[0]} onRemove={onRemove} />
    )}
  </div>
}

function Item({ item, uuid, onRemove }) {
  const data = item[uuid]
  return <div>
    <h3>{uuid}</h3>
    <pre>{JSON.stringify(data)}</pre>
    <button type="button" onClick={onRemove(uuid)}>❌</button>
  </div>
}

const data = [
  {
    "4b080412-b22c-40fe-a67e-510f96d50063":{
      id: 1231,
      name: "Anna",
      department: "Business"
    }
  },
  {
    "8d319764-a49e-4465-a166-a701a5cc2b77":{
      id: 456,
      name: "Tony",
      department: "Marketing"
    }
  },
  {
    "23ea617b-210e-4329-9ab1-ecd2afa12e4d":{
      id: 99,
      name: "Francis",
      department: "Sales"
    }
  },
]


ReactDOM.render(<App initData={data} />, document.body)
```

```css
div > div { background-color: #eee; margin-bottom: 1rem; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```